# Replace attr value using const

Tags: javascript, constants, attr

when I try to modify the attr of an input, for example "data-disabled-dates" replacing the content with a const, the result I get is a text with the name of the const, but not the const content, which would be the correct way to get it.

html

```
<input data-min-date="+1" data-disabled-dates="24/12/2021; 25/12/2021; 30/12/2021; 31/12/2021">
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
const dateObj = new Date();
jQuery("input[data-min-date='+1']").attr('data-disabled-dates','dateObj');
```

So the wrong result is:

```
<input data-min-date="+1" data-disabled-dates="dateObj">
```

The result i want (today):

```
<input data-min-date="+1" data-disabled-dates="16/11/2021">
```

Comment: Because you are passing `'dateObj'` string and not the variable. It should be `.attr('data-disabled-dates', dateObj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrapped the name of the const in quotes so it became a string.

solution:

```js
const dateObj = new Date();
jQuery("input[data-min-date='+1']").attr('data-disabled-dates',dateObj);
```

or if you really want date to be formatted like dd/MM/YYYY:

```js
const now = new Date();
jQuery("input[data-min-date='+1']").attr(
  'data-disabled-dates', 
  `${now.getDate()}/${now.getMonth()+1}/${now.getFullYear()}`
);
```